# Ionic 2 update specific child with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I want to update specific data in Firebase, 2 cases:

1. I want to update specific child as shows in this photo:

[image]

2. i have list of courses that chosen with ion-select in ionic 2 and i want to update\push each of them below the courses key
   for example:

in firebase it will be like that:

courses:{
     0: course1,
     1: course2,
     2:course3
};

I tried this code but it's not works

```
select_courseFun(course_array:any){
    var counter=0;
    for(let c of course_array){
        counter++;
        this.coursesPref.update(counter.toString(),{
        name: c
        });
    }
}
```